# Conditional Formatting based on a dependent drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two worksheets:

A) CF [Screentshot of worksheet "CF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrt4e.jpg):

1. A Drop down list is located in cell A2. This list consists of all 12 months. The source of this list is from the worksheet "Mapping_Others" [Screenshot of the worksheet "Mapping_Others"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9OS.jpg). For example I choose the month march from the drop-down list.
2. In the cell "O6", I have a sumif formula which is based on the Dropdown list and return the sum of the selected month. The formula is

   **=SUMIF($C$3:$N$3;"<="&INDEX(Mapping_Others!$A$2:$A$13;MATCH(CF!$A$2;Mapping_Others!$C$2:$C$13;0));$C6:$N6)**

   - **$C$3:$N$3**: range which contain 1,..., 12.
   - **Mapping_Others!$A$2:$A$13**:range which contain 1,...,12
   - **Mapping_Others!$C$2:$C$13**: range which is the source of the drop-down list
   - **$C6:$N6**: The range to be summed

As I choose March from the drop down list, the sum if will sum up the range "C6:E6"

3. **What I expect to happen:** *I would like to have a conditional formatting to have a red border line on range "C4:E8" because it includes from January to March. So, if I select the April, the sumIf will summ from January to April, and I want a red border line on range "C4:F8" which covers from January to April.*

**More Worksheets**

B)  Mapping Other: The source of the Dropdown list. [Screenshot of the worksheet "Mapping_Others"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9OS.jpg)

Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edited question, you can use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=COLUMN()-2<=MATCH($A$2,Mapping_Others!$C$2:$C$13,0)
```

Applied to the following range: `=$C$4:$N$6`

Comment: Worked fine when I tested it. Can you please edit your qeustion to show us what the expected result is exactly? Along with more details on *how* it did not work

Comment: I edited the question again. :-)  I copied and pasted the same function "=COLUMN()-2<=MATCH($A$2,$U$1:$U$12,0)", and I updated the cell sources, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown list relates to one particular cell, the value being "January", "February", .... You can configure conditional formatting, based on a formula, referring to that cell (in my example that cell is `A1`):

- For the cells you want to colour when "January" is selected, use the formula: `=A1="January"`
- For the cells you want to colour when "February" is selected, use the formula: `=A1="February"`
- ...